# ASP.NET default.aspx page very slow to load every time

Tags: asp.net, performance, load

I have a simply site that uses a masterpage.  I have a couple of pages that use that masterpage.  However, the default.aspx page takes just over 15 seconds to load every time the page is loaded.  The default.aspx page only contains a label and there is nothing in the page load event.  All the other pages load very quickly and they all contain a lot of code in their page load event.  They also use the same masterpage.

Does anyone know why this is happening ?  I've set the page trace and I can see that the time between load begin and load end time is just over 15 seconds.  The other more complex pages take under 2 seconds to load.

I've created a new master page and set the default.aspx page to use that and the problem still persists so I think it's the default.aspx page that has the problem.  I'm not sure why as there is almost nothing in the default.aspx page.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Can you put some code from the master page?

Comment: SharePoint by any chance, run on your local machine?

Comment: I'm not using sharepoint.  I'll post up the code for you to see.

Comment: Is this site database driven? Is the problem with the default.aspx page, or is that a coincidence because there is something happening on the first page load for a user session (e.g. connectivity problems with a database)?

Comment: do you have a lot of breakpoints in your code? try deleting them all, it solved the problem i had.